# Losing fields when filling C++ std::map

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem in using the std::map correctly. The class `Example` is a class with an ID, a label, a vector of keypoints and a descriptor matrix. The class `Examples` is a map for retrieving an example given its ID. The examples are read from files on disk, stored in the map, then used later.

Even if it is conceptually very simple, I am not able to fill the map properly.

I have the following class:

```
class Example
{
public:
    std::string id;
    std::string label;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    cv::Mat descriptors;

    Example(std::string id_, std::string label_)
        : id(id_), label(label_)
    {
        // ... nothing ...
    }

    string to_string() const
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "@" << id
        << " (" << label << ")"
        << " - #keypoints " << keypoints.size()
        << ", descr " << descriptors.rows << " x " << descriptors.cols;
        return ss.str();
    } // to_string

}; // class Example

ostream& operator <<(ostream & out, const Example &ex)
{
    out << ex.to_string();
    return out;
} // operator <<
```

And this one:

```
 // OLD: class Examples : public std::map<std::string, Example*> {
    class Examples {
    // New line after Martini's comment
    std::map<std::string, Example*> _map;
    [...]   
    void fill() {
       // create an example
       Example *example = new Example(id, label); 

       // inputstream in

       // Read all the keypoints
       cv::KeyPoint p;
       for(int i=0; ... ) {
            in.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p), sizeof(cv::KeyPoint));
            example->keypoints.push_back(p); // push_back copies p
       } // for 

       // ... misc code

       cv::Mat descr(n_keypoints, d_size, cv_type, cv::Scalar(1));
       // ... read Mat from inputstream in, then assign it to the example
       example->descriptors = descr;


       // SEE THE OUTPUT BELOW
       std::cout << "INSERT THIS: " << (*example) << std::endl;
       _map.insert(std::pair<string,Example*>(id, example));
       std::cout << "READ THIS: " << *(get_example(id)) << std::endl;

       // ... other code
    } // fill

    // Code modified after Martini's comment.
    Example* get_example(const std::string &id) const {
        std::map<std::string, Example*>::const_iterator it = _map.find(id);
        if( it == _map.end()) {
            // ... manage error
            // ... then exit
        } // if
        return it->second;
    } // get_example


} // class Examples
```

The output from the insert/get lines is:

```
 INSERT THIS: @122225084 (label) - #keypoints 711, descr 711 x 128
 READ THIS: @122225084 (label) - #keypoints 0, descr 0 x 0
```

In the insert I had a pointer to an example with 711 keypoints and a 711x128 descriptor matrix. If I read the example using its ID right after the insert, I get a pointer to an example with 0 keypoints and an empty matrix.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You must not extend `std::map` class. STL containers are not designed to be inherited (for instance their destructor is not virtual). You should consider composition, i.e. using a map as a field in the `Examples` class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I modified the code (now Examples has a field of type map<...> and does not extend it), but the problem persists.

Comment: I don't know how you redefined the `operator<<` on the `Example` class, however I suggest you to use a debugger to inspect the return value of `get_example(id)` instead of relying on standard output prints.

Comment: [I did not know it is not possible to format comments]

class Example {... 

string to_string() const {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "@" << id << " (" << label << ")" << " - #keypoints " << keypoints.size() << ", descr " << descriptors.rows
              << " x "  << descriptors.cols;
        return ss.str();
    } // to_string

}; 


ostream& operator <<(ostream & out, const Example &ex) {
    out << ex.to_string();
    return out;
} // operator <<

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor for `Example`?

Comment: @AntonioSesto you shouldn't need one from what i see in this code. You  never seem to make any copies (which would be easy enough to verify; just declare `private: Example(const Example&);` in the `Example` class decl. If it compiles, no copies are being made). All I see you doing is throwing around a bunch of naked pointers (which I would replace with `std::shared_ptr<Example>`, but thats a separate issue), so I don't expect it would make a difference.

Comment: I did not before your comment because I never copy instance of Examples. However, now there is both a copy constructor and the operator '=' overwritten. They are never called.

Comment: @AntonioSesto I've tried to replicate this issue with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and have been unable to do so. Any chance you can cut this down?

Comment: @WHozCraig: I tried 'private ...', it compiles.

Comment: @AntonioSesto I figured it would just by what I see in the question.

Comment: @AntonioSesto Updated your question to include the stream-dump code. You might wanna check it out to make sure it is accurate, but I think it is. Still trying to figure out why you're fetched example would be different. I may suggest you dump `this` along with the other data just to make sure they point to the same object, but I can't see how they couldn't right now.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am moving to implement it in a different way and try to solve it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into your code one possible explanation is that you already have element in the map with the same key. To diagnose that first of all print value of pointer before you add object and after that (something like this):

```
std::cout << "INSERT THIS: " << (void *)example << " " << (*example) << std::endl;
_map.insert(std::pair<string,Example*>(id, example));
std::cout << "READ THIS: " << (void *)get_example(id) << " " << *(get_example(id)) << std::endl;
```

Next or another way is to check result of insert:

```
if( !_map.insert(std::pair<string,Example*>(id, example)).second ) 
    std::cout << "ERROR: example:" << id << " is already there";
```

If you want to override element unconditionally you can use oprator[]:

```
_map[ id ] = example;
```

If there are really duplicates you will get memory leak (you are getting it anyway) so I would strongly recommend to use smart pointer to store data in your map.